# How do you launch a WPF front end as a DLL from another assembly?

Tags: wpf, dll, assemblies

How does one create a WPF front-end that has an Application object from within another application (an existing MFC / CLR application, but that's another story)? The existence of the Application as the entry point of the assembly seems to prevent such a use.  Certainly, you can use a WPF application as an assembly. Can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I have made an plugin in WPF for winforms app (I used ElementHost Class). It was in another assembly due to a few reasons.

Comment: As I stated parenthetically, I am not trying to interop with WinForms.  I am stuck with MFC.